# Generators of the first singular homology group of a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface embedded in $\mathbb C^2$ with coordinates $(z,w)$ and let $\pi_z \colon X \to \mathbb C$ be the projection on first coordinate with property that that for cofinite number of points $z \in \mathbb C$ there exists a neighborhood $U_z$, containing $z$, and there exist neighborhoods of points in $\pi^{-1}(z)$ such that $\pi_z$ is the biholomorphic map from each of these neighborhoods to $U_z$. For a finite number of points $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ we allow to have some points in $\pi^{-1}(z_0)$ such that they have neighborhoods with local coordinates $u$ in which the map is just $z-z_0 = u^k$, $k \geq 2$. Now let $\{\gamma_j\}$ be a collection of small closed curves of the form $u = \varepsilon e^{i\varphi}$, $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$, $\varepsilon$ is small, around these specific points. Is it true that collection $\{\gamma_j\}$ generates $H_1^s(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because these cycles are contractible, i.e. they are null-homologous. Just let $\epsilon$ shrink to $0$.

Comment: Ah, really. On the other hand the definition of Riemann surface is corrupted by existence of these of these exceptional points, isn't it? So maybe I need to exclude these points from $X$ and after this $\{\gamma_j\}$ will generate the first homology group?

Comment: @Nimza Why do you say the definition is "corrupted" by the existence of these points? The points which you describe (which are called "ramification points") are really objects which belong to the *morphism* $f : X\to \mathbf C$. They are not intrinsic to $X$. In any case, if you want to exclude these points from $X$ then indeed $\gamma_j$ will no longer be null-homologous, but they will represent homology classes on $X$ minus the ramification locus, not homology classes on $X$.